# C++: Is it possible to condense `bool` objects within the same byte?

Tags: c++, memory, boolean, byte, bit

Consider a class with a number of bool attributes

```
class A
{
  bool a;
  bool b;
  bool c;
  bool d;
  bool e;
  bool f;
};
```

While each `bool` object could be represented with a single bit, here each attribute would take a byte (if I am not mistaken). The object would take 6 bytes instead of just 1 byte (6 bits of which would be actually used). The reason being that bits are not addressable, only bytes are.

To condensate the memory a bit, one could use a `vector<bool>` or a `bitset` and then access the attributes, by their indices. For example, one could write a get function as

```
bool A::get_d() {data[3];}
```

Ideally, I would love being able to directly access the attributes with `InstanceOfA.d`. Is it possible to do that, while ensuring that all of my 6 `bool` are being condensed within the same byte?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). Works with Repl.it's gcc version 4.6.3.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test 
{
  bool a:1;
  bool b:1;
  bool c:1;
  bool d:1;
  bool e:1;
  bool f:1;
  bool g:1;
  bool h:1;
  //bool i:1; //would increase size to 2 bytes.
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  std::cout << sizeof(t) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: Another alternative is `std::bitset`.

Comment: Note, however, that the actual layout of those fields is implementation-defined. The language definition does not require them to be packed. Typically they will be, but if it’s important, check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about saving space, you should probably use a [`bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) instead of a bit field.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998129/9614249) for a full comparison, but essentially a bit field will have some overhead due to being struct and the compiler may or may not actually pack elements together in order to save space.

Bitsets however are specifically made to optimize space allocation, and also offer some helpful functions specifically for bit twiddling.

A bitset is logically just an array of bits, but packed to save space. You can use it like such:

```
std::bitset<8> bacon;
bacon.set();    // 11111111
bacon.reset(1); // 11111101 Note: counts index from the right

std::bitset<4> fancy (std::string("1111"));
fancy[1] = 0;      // 1101 Note: counts index from the right
fancy.test(1) == 0 // true
```